# Restore locked mode fails on error NU1004: The packages lock file is inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have 2 C# projects: `Project.csproj` and `Project.Tests.csproj`.

`Project.Tests.csproj` contains `ProjectReference`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../Project/Project.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I use floating versions of dependencies and I also enabled lock files:

```
<RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
<DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>true</DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>
<RestoreLockedMode>false</RestoreLockedMode>
```

When I execute `dotnet restore --locked-mode`, I'm getting

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.409/NuGet.targets(128,5): error NU1004: The packages lock file is inconsistent with the project dependencies so restore can't be run in locked mode. Disable the RestoreLockedMode MSBuild property or pass an explicit --force-evaluate option to run restore to update the lock file.
```

When I try suggestion `dotnet restore --force-evaluate`, it is restored correctly, there are no changes to lock files though.
Funnily enough, when I execute `dotnet restore --locked-mode` right after, it fails on the same `error NU1004`

Do you have any idea how to overcome this issue?
Is there a way to tell NuGet to provide more descriptive information why it fails?

Comment: Hi, did you get to the bottom of it in the end? I'm facing a similar issue.